# SQL count rows without using Count()

Tags: sql, count

I have a table like this:

```
Name     Food
Tom     |Ice Cream
Tom     |Apple
Sam     |Burger
Tom     |Burger
Jim     |Ice Cream
Sam     |Ice Cream
```

I need to select the names of the kids that like at least two types of food without using `Count()` so the result should look like:

```
Name     c
Tom     |3
Sam     |2
```

Our university teacher said that we should try this by multiplying the table with itself but I couldn't find or come up with a solution.
This code would be equivalent with the desired code:

```
select name from (select name, count(*) as c from kids group by name) where c>1;
```

Comment: Hint:   Your professor is referring to a self-join.

Comment: Thanks! I'll read-up on it.

Comment: Do you have to return just the names or the count as well? Based on your description I suspect the count is not relevant.

Comment: It doesn't matter according to the task description, but if I could return the count it'd be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution...

```
declare @tempTable table (name varchar(max), food varchar(max))
insert into @tempTable select 'Tom', 'Ice Cream'
insert into @tempTable select 'Tom', 'Apple'
insert into @tempTable select 'Sam', 'Burger'
insert into @tempTable select 'Tom', 'Burger'
insert into @tempTable select 'Jim', 'Ice Cream'
insert into @tempTable select 'Sam', 'Ice Cream'

select distinct t1.name from @tempTable t1 join @tempTable t2 on t2.name = t1.name and t2.name+t2.food <> t1.name+t1.food
```

This would not show you the count since we can't have the count(*), but does tell you who have more than one.

Comment: I think this works, but at the end why do we add t2.name+t2.food? Isn't that supposed to be just t2.food?

Comment: I am concatenating t2.name and t2.food to make sure to find the ones that are "different"... technically counting the ones that have not been included already part of the t1 select. In other words, Jim+Ice Cream was found already, which means the t2.name+t2.food which also is Jim+Ice Cream is not returned. However, the Sam+Burger found first returns Sam since there's more than just Sam+Burger but also Sam+Ice Cream... does this make sense?

Comment: I get an error when I try to concatenate t2.name+t2.food and t1.name+t1.food, but it works with just t2.food <> t1.food

Comment: I suppose t2.food <> t1.food may be enough but from the table of results you originally posted, replicated in my declare @tempTable and insert into, it was working... not sure why it was not working for you.

Comment: dunno either ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number. this is the error I get

Answer (score 3):

Would this work?

```
declare @tempTable table (name varchar(max), food varchar(max))
insert into @tempTable select 'Tom', 'Ice Cream'
insert into @tempTable select 'Tom', 'Apple'
insert into @tempTable select 'Sam', 'Burger'
insert into @tempTable select 'Tom', 'Burger'
insert into @tempTable select 'Jim', 'Ice Cream'
insert into @tempTable select 'Sam', 'Ice Cream'

select t1.name, 0+SUM(1) from @tempTable t1 group by t1.name having SUM(1)>1
```

results
name    (No column name)
Sam 2
Tom 3

Answer (score 0):

Untested SQL solution.

```
select a.name from kids a, kids b 
where a.name = b.name and a.food != b.food
group by a.name;
```

Not sure why your professor is forcing you to write a sub-optimal solution but I suppose it will give you insight into how joins work.

Final solution as tested!

```
select distinct a.name from kids a, kids b 
where a.name = b.name 
  and a.food != b.food;
```

Comment: This works like a charm, but if we remove group by and add distinct before a.name on the select we get the result. Thanks!

Comment: @Usagi -- The professors sql does not display count either!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT a1.name, 1 + SUM( 1 ) AS c
FROM kids AS a1  JOIN kids AS a2 ON a1.name = a2.name AND a1.food <> a2.food
GROUP BY a1.name
HAVING SUM( 1 ) > 0
```

Comment: I don't think you tested that :)

Comment: Did not... Why?

Comment: Count is wrong. Sam,3; Tom 7. However I suspect the count is not relevant to the question.

Comment: This seems to work, but the counts are off. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 0):

use simply group by

```
  select name ,count(*) from tab group by name
  having count(*)>1
```

no need any subquery

Comment: I can't use count unfortunately